# differencing time series using diff in r

Tags: r

Looking at [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diff.html) what does:

```
diff(SomeTimeSeries)
```

do? Does it by default do:

```
diff(SomeTimeSeries, differences = 1)
```

Or does it use ndiff to define the correct value for differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the **Usage** section of the `diff` help file (`?diff`), you can see that, yes, by default `differences` argument is set to 1. This "works" for every single function in R.

```
diff(x, ...)

## Default S3 method:
diff(x, lag = 1, differences = 1, ...)

## S3 method for class 'POSIXt'
diff(x, lag = 1, differences = 1, ...)

## S3 method for class 'Date'
diff(x, lag = 1, differences = 1, ...)
```